# Background in title

Tags: android, background, android-cardview

How i do this blue background in this title on cardview?

[image]

I try put a linear layout with blue background, but this make android with SO 19 or worse crash app

this cardview is a template for listview items

- Cardview:

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imagem"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/a_receber" />

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="16dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:background="@drawable/bordas_cardview_azul"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_vencimento"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:textColor="#fff"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:text="Titulo"
          android:textSize="11sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_emissao"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_vencimento"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:text="telefone1"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_nome"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_emissao"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:text="celular"
          android:textSize="12sp" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_deve"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_nome"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:text="renda"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_valorini"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_deve"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:text="limite"
          android:textSize="12sp" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_status"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_valorini"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:text="bandeira"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_id"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_status"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagem"
          android:text="id"
          android:visibility="gone" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

drawable/bordas_cardview_azul of linear layout

```
 <shape
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" >

 <solid
    android:color="#1874CD"/>

<corners
    android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>

</shape>
```

When i try start in android with SO 20 or betters, it start normal, without problem, but with previous ones to stop working

logcat with android api 19:

> Process: insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.forbusiness, PID: 1915
>                                                                                           android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class 
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                               at insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.forbusiness.adapater.AdapterCursosPersonalizado.getView(AdapterCursosPersonalizado.java:40)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1795)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1167)
>                                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:852)
>                                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:871)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                             at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
>                                                                                             at android.

Adapter listview

```
  public class AdapterContasPersonalizado extends BaseAdapter {

private final List<Curso2> cursos;
private final contas act;

public AdapterContasPersonalizado(List<Curso2> cursos, contas act) {
    this.cursos = cursos;
    this.act = act;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cursos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return cursos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 //line 40 below
    View view = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_contas_personalizada, parent, false);

    Curso2 curso = cursos.get(position);

    ImageView imagem = (ImageView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.imagem);
    TextView vencimento = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_vencimento);
    TextView emissao = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_emissao);
    TextView nome = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_nome);
    TextView devendo = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_deve);
    TextView valorini = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_valorini);
    TextView status = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_status);
    TextView id = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_id);

    vencimento.setText(curso.getVencimento());
    emissao.setText(curso.getEmissao());
    nome.setText(curso.getNome2());
    devendo.setText(curso.getDevendo());
    valorini.setText(curso.getValorini());
    status.setText(curso.getStatus2());
    id.setText(curso.getId2());

    return view;
}
}
```

The error occurs only in the insert in the listview, because when using a cardview normally, it does not display errors

Comment: Please post your code and crash log.

Comment: @Nfear one minute

Comment: @Nfear done, I add

Answer (score 0):

This inflate exception is caused because of large size of your drawable assets. 
Remove background drawables to appropriate folder like drawable-hdpi or use colour codes to get correct colours.